# Elements of the Group $\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^3,(ab)^8,(ab)^4(ab^{-1})^4 \rangle.$

Tags: finite-groups, gap

Consider the group $\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^3,(ab)^8,(ab)^4(ab^{-1})^4 \rangle$ Which is general linear group $GL(2,3)$ by GAP as I tried below

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b");
<free group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> a:=f.1;;b:=f.2;;
gap> g:=f/[a^2,b^3,(a*b)^8,(a*b)^4*(a*b^-1)^4];;
gap> Size(g);
48
gap> StructureDescription(g);
"GL(2,3)"
```

Now i want all $48$   elements of the group $\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^3,(ab)^8,(ab)^4(ab^{-1})^4 \rangle$ in the form of $a$ and $b$ only i.e. words in $a$ and $b$ like $\{e,,a,b,b^{2},ab,(ab)^{2},\cdot\cdot\cdot (ab)^{7}\cdot\cdot\cdot\}.$
Please help me to find all $48$ elements of the group. Is there some algorithm in GAP to find out elements. Thank you.

Comment: You could probably work this out by finding where the isomorphism $\langle a,b | a^2,b^3,(ab)^8, (ab)^4(ab^{-1})^4\rangle \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(2,3)$ takes $a$ and $b$ (since you just need to find a pair of matrices with the desired properties). Then, you can do all your computation with matrices, which at least gives a clear algorithm. ([This page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/General_linear_group:GL(2,3)) might be useful in doing that)

Comment: But manually it will take a lot of time....

Comment: It could be done algorithmically; one can basically use some search algorithm on $\operatorname{GL}(2,3)$ to find a path from the identity to everything else in the Cayley graph once you find the generators. Plus, one can find the generators just by testing out all the options, since there's not that many. (But I'm not saying this is the best way, so I'll leave it as a comment)

Comment: $a=\begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 1  \\
    2       & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 0  \\
    0       & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: These are generators.... now can you tell me algorithm....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GAP, you can ask for `Elements` for any finite group and get (memory permitting) a list of elements. So you could do this for your group `g`.
Caveat: GAP does (for good reasons which I do not want to elaborate here) not by default reduce word expressions. So you will get a nicer result by forcing reduced multiplication (using an ad-hoc length-based rewriting system:

```
gap> SetReducedMultiplication(g);
gap> Elements(g);
[ <identity ...>, a, b^-1, b, a*b^-1, a*b, b^-1*a, b*a, a*b^-1*a, a*b*a,
  b^-1*a*b^-1, b^-1*a*b, b*a*b^-1, b*a*b, (a*b^-1)^2, a*b^-1*a*b, a*b*a*b^-1,
  (a*b)^2, (b^-1*a)^2, b^-1*a*b*a, b*a*b^-1*a, (b*a)^2, (a*b^-1)^2*a,
  a*b^-1*a*b*a, a*b*a*b^-1*a, (a*b)^2*a, (b^-1*a)^2*b^-1, (b^-1*a)^2*b,
  b^-1*a*b*a*b^-1, b^-1*(a*b)^2, b*(a*b^-1)^2, b*a*b^-1*a*b, (b*a)^2*b^-1,
  (b*a)^2*b, (a*b^-1)^3, (a*b)^3, (b^-1*a)^3, (b^-1*a)^2*b*a,
  b^-1*a*b*a*b^-1*a, b^-1*(a*b)^2*a, b*(a*b^-1)^2*a, b*a*b^-1*a*b*a,
  (b*a)^2*b^-1*a, (b*a)^3, (a*b^-1)^3*a, (a*b)^3*a, (b*a)^3*b, (b*a)^4 ]
```

Comment: Thanks..........

Comment: you always gives very nice and helpful solution.....thanku very much .....